# "Not enough values to unpack" when iterating over dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm getting a value error `Not enough Values to unpack. Expected 3, got 2` when turning a dictionary into a list of tuples via a list comprehension.

```py
# Link MPNs to sales reps
sam_parts = {}
for row in plmdata:
    mpn,sam = row[5],row[24]
    mpn_heat = heatscores[mpn]
    if sam not in sam_parts:
        sam_parts[sam] = {mpn:mpn_heat}
    elif mpn not in sam_parts[sam]:
        sam_parts[sam][mpn] = mpn_heat

# Convert sam_parts to list of tuples
clean_parts = [(sam,mpn,mpn_heat) for sam,mpn,mpn_heat in sam_parts.items()]
```

The offending list comprehension is towards the bottom. I included code for the dictionary just in case. I'm sure there's a straightforward solution here that I'm just not seeing, but I need a fresh pair of eyes! Thanks in advance.

Comment: because sam_parts.items() gives a 2 item tuple (key, value). I'm not sure tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, `dict.items` will return tuples with 2 items, even if the associated value is a dictionary itself. Assuming you want the two levels of keys and the associated value, here's how I would handle it:

```
[(sam, mpn, mpn_heat) for sam, inner_dict in sam_parts.items() for mpn, mpn_heat in inner_dict.items()]
```

This is essentially a nested for loop to go through the "outer" dictionary and then the dictionaries inside it.

Comment: @Pietro Marsella and busybear of course, yes absolutely this fixed it! I wasn't even thinking about 'sam_parts.items' generating only a 2-item tuple. Your nested for loop suggestion fixed the issue, and actually saved me a little effort in making the output what i wanted! Thank you both.